# Can't see workflow settings in Drupal content type edition

Tags: drupal-6, internationalization

Someone gave me a drupal site made with drupal 6.19 in order to add the i18n module.
I'm trying to follow the instructions listed here:

http://www.isegura.es/blog/drupal-multiple-languages-part-two-content-types-configuration

I have already installed and enabled the i18n module however, I have an issue with this part:

*Go to Administer > Content Management > Content types > Pages > Edit. Go to the bottom of the page. You'll find a section called "workflow settings". Open it and activate Multilingual Support.*

I can't find the workflow settings anywhere, I checked the source code of the page and I saw that the section is hidden with display:none but I don't know why... I checked and re-checked the admin user permissions but I don't have a clue, I haven't worked with drupal in my life either. Can somebody help me?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What theme are you using? If you're using a custom theme you might try switching to Garland or another core theme, for a bit, in order to do this. Because it seems that someone decided to hide those settings through CSS in your current theme.

Comment: Thanks Alexender, finally I solved this issue doing that. Post your comment as a solution and I will be glad to vote your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my comment: Try switching to Garland (or any core theme that you know hasn't been tampered with) to see if you can see everything and do what you need to do, because it seems that someone decided to hide those settings through CSS in your current theme.